# How to complete unfinished installation in ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: installation, software-center, uninstall

Hi i have installed ubuntu 10.04 on my desktop.

After installing i kept some softwares to install using ubuntu software center and while it was installing the power went and i hibernated the system.

My problem is that when i came back and tried to reinstall the applications it didnot work and now am unable to reinstall the softwares and also cannot uninstall the softwares can any one tell me how to fix this as i am new to ubuntu.

Comment: first is why 10.04? It is very old version and will not be supported in this site either when reaches to [EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29). Can you execute `sudo apt-get install -f` or you can try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: ok ill try these and i installed 10.04 coz my desktop is really old with p4 256mb ram and 80gb harddisk so i dunno whether it supports 12.04 or 12.10...

Comment: Okey. Then it is fine. 12.04 will be heavy on it. You can try lubuntu or xubuntu. :)

Comment: :) thanks ill try the above commands first and let you know and any way when i tried to upgrade it to 12.04 it gave me a error saying some of the graphics features may not be supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is really old with p4 256mb ram

Then by far out is Lubuntu the only choise you have; Xubuntu requires for about 512Mb RAM for a reasenable work-flow.

10.04 is almost EOL. The solutions above in the comments could work :) .

Of course if you can upgrade your RAM-memory up to 1Gb, then you can easily work with Xubuntu, what is more a vivid operating system than Lubuntu. 
These RAM-banks can be easily found second hand, and sometimes even new in several webshops.
I'd suggest that this is an option you simply can't refuse (lol) .

At the other hand a P4 is mostly an older computer what should be replaced for something from the newest generation, but that is, for Xubuntu, not entire nessecary.

I'd go for the RAM-upgrade (this is the cheapest way for catching up with the new generations of Linux) .

Comment: Thank you i was thinking of a ram upgrade but wanted to see whether this works first and whether ill be able to install ubuntu on my system thats all its all curiosity purpose...:)